# Matching results completely different in R and Stata

Tags: r, stata, matching

I am trying to match treatment with the control using the `R Matching package` for the data set nuclearplants (which is available in `optmatch package in R`). Following is the code for matching:

```
library (optmatch)# for the dataset nuclearplants
library(Matching) # for performing matching
data(nuclearplants)
# I am using Mahalanobis matching with covariates t1 and t2 and treatment pr
cov<-cbind(nuclearplants$t1,nuclearplants$t2)
sd<-Match(Y=NULL,Tr=nuclearplants$pr,X=cov, Weight.matrix = 2 ) 
    matched<-rbind(nuclearplants[sd$index.treated,],nuclearplants[sd$index.control,])
head(matched)


       cost  date t1 t2  cap pr ne ct bw cum.n pt
A 443.22 67.33 10 85 1065  1  0  1  0     1  0
B 642.23 68.00 11 78 1065  1  1  1  0    12  0
C 457.12 68.42 15 55  822  1  0  0  0     5  0
D 289.66 68.42 15 76  530  1  0  1  0     2  0
E 490.88 68.92 16 59 1050  1  0  0  0     8  0
F 665.99 70.92 22 57  828  1  1  0  0    20  0
> sd$index.treated
      [1]  3  5  9 18 20 22 24 30 31 32
    > sd$index.control
 [1]  2 10  8 19 23 26 26 10 10  2
```

Now, I am trying to see whether the `stata` also gives the same results for the same data and the same methodology. For this purpose, I use `psmatch 2`

```
psmatch2 pr, mahalanobis(t1 t2)
```

I was very shocked to see that for the same approach, these two programs give different results. Below is the summary results for the stata:

```
tre stata control
3   7
5   7
9   6
18  15
20  17
22  19
24  14
30  7
31  7
32  2

tr: treatment observations (row number), stata control=control observations for Stata (row number)
```

I was wondering whether I missed something implicit in the code.

Comment: Not an answer, but a picky point. In `Stata`, which I know much better, `psmatch2` [NB] is one user-written program; therefore it is loose to attribute results to `Stata`. Similar point, I guess, for `R`.

Comment: @ Nick : Exactly!

Comment: It doesn't fix the disparity, but in your R code, it seems like you should use `Weight=2` rather than `Weight.matrix=2`. `Weight` sets it to use Mahalanobis matching, and `Weight.matrix` sets the weighting matrix manually.

Comment: @ pwfoley: Thanks for that (question now updated). Any idea why they are giving different results when the approach is the same and idea of minimizing the distance is same? I would really appreciate the input.

Comment: @user1493368 What type of matching do you intend to do? Optimal matching? Matching with replacement?  (Non)bipartite matching? These are different things. What is the Stata routine doing?

Comment: Its called Mahalanobis matching [without propensity scores]. Stata doesn't allow matching without replacement for this option. So, I think this is matching with replacement. Stata details [here](http://fmwww.bc.edu/repec/bocode/p/psmatch2.html).

Comment: Once again, this is not Stata speaking. Stata has no view on this. It's `psmatch2`.