# Computing the Mahalanobis distance in user written function psmatch2 of Stata

Tags: r, stata, distance-functions, matching

This is my attempt to find the discrepancy in the matching process for `R` package `"Matching"` and user written function `"psmatch2"` in `Stata` [[Details]](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/52889/matching-results-completely-different-in-r-and-stata).

I am trying to find out how the Mahalanobis distance is computed in `psmatch2` (user written function for `Stata`) and whether it is consistent with the Mahalanobis distance computed in `R` and that computed using matrix in `Stata` [Details for Stata is available [here]](http://www.stata.com/statalist/archive/2010-10/msg01294.html).

Following is the code for computing [Mahalanobis](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/mahalanobis.html) distance in R. The data I used is nuclearplants data from `optmatch (R package)`.

```
    library (optmatch)# for the dataset nuclearplants
    data(nuclearplants) # pr is a treatment variable
head(nuclearplants)
    cost  date t1 t2  cap pr ne ct bw cum.n pt
H 460.05 68.58 14 46  687  0  1  0  0    14  0
I 452.99 67.33 10 73 1065  0  0  1  0     1  0
A 443.22 67.33 10 85 1065  1  0  1  0     1  0
J 652.32 68.00 11 67 1065  0  1  1  0    12  0
B 642.23 68.00 11 78 1065  1  1  1  0    12  0
K 345.39 67.92 13 51  514  0  1  1  0     3  0
   library(foreign)
   write.dta(nuclearplants,"datanp.dta")
    covar<-cbind(nuclearplants$t1,nuclearplants$t2) #co-variates t1 and t2
   X<-covar

#compute Mahalanobis distance for the treatment (pr=1) in row 7 and control (pr=0) in row 3
kk<-solve(cov(X))
kk
           [,1]       [,2]
[1,] 0.11362947 0.01747102
[2,] 0.01747102 0.01194136
mahalanobis(X[7,], center=X[3,], cov=kk, inverted=TRUE)
[1] 12.63674
#compute Mahalanobis distance for the treatment (pr=1) in row 2 and control (pr=0) in row 3
mahalanobis(X[2,], center=X[3,], cov=cov(X))
[1] 1.719555
```

###########`Perform above steps in Stata using matrix`############

```
I computed the covariance matrix in Stata as follows:

mat accum cov =  t1 t2, dev noc
mat covinv=inv(cov/(r(N)-2)) # psmatch2 function divides by N-2
mat list covinv
symmetric covinv[2,2]
           t1         t2
t1  .10996401
t2  .01690744  .01155615

#This is different from the inverse of covariance matrix compute above in R. However, dividing by N-1 gives the same answer (I am not sure why we have to divide by N-2 in psmatch2) 

mat covinv=inv(cov/(r(N)-1))
mat list covinv
symmetric covinv[2,2]
           t1         t2
t1  .11362947
t2  .01747102  .01194136
# For now I stick to one with N-1
mean(t1)
mean(t2)

Next for the treatment 3 we have X[3,]:-3.75  22.625  {this is obtained as 10-mean(t1) and 85 minus mean(t2))
and for the control X[7,]: -1.75 -12.375 {this is obtained as 12-mean(t1) and 50 minus mean(t2))

Now Mahalanobis Distance: (X[7,]-X[3,]) *covinv*(X[7,]-X[3,]) =12.2291 (This will be the same as in R if we use N-1 in variance computation in psmatch22)

Similarly, for the treatment 3 and control 2 this is
(X2[2,]-X2[3,])*covinv* (X2[2,]-X2[3,])=1.664086 (This will be same as in R if we use N-1 in variance computation in psmatch2.
```

So, up to now, I showed that results from `R` and `Stata` matches if we stick to computing using variance with N-1 instead of N-2 (as in psmatch2). However, when I run the `psmatch2`

```
psmatch2 pr, mahalanobis(t1 t2)
```

and obtain the Mahalanobis distance (This is given as `_mdif` in `psmatch 2` : `_mdif` In the case of one-to-one Mahalanobis matching, for every treatment observation it stores the absolute distance to its matched control in terms of the Mahalanobis metric).

```
Mahalanobis distance for the treatment (pr=1) in row 7 and control (pr=0) in row 3 
2.26469
```

Note: It doesn't provides Mahalanobis distance for the treatment (pr=1) in row 2 and control (pr=0) in row 3 because it provides the distance only for the matched observation.

My question is why  Mahalanobis distance (2.26469) computed using `psmatch2` is different than that computed using `R` (12.63674) and matrix function in `Stata` (12.63674 for variance computed using N-1)?

Comment: In effect this is your second go at this -- compare http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/52889/matching-results-completely-different-in-r-and-stata -- but not much is happening here. Concentrating on the Stata side of this: Did you look at the code of `psmatch2` (BTW, a command, _not_ a function)? Did you think of asking on Statalist (more people watching than here)? Did you contact the authors? Similar questions for R.

Comment: You can check your answer with the user written function [mahapick](http://ideas.repec.org/c/boc/bocode/s456703.html) in `stata.`

Comment: @Nick : Thank you for the suggestion. Yes, I did look into the function. I will correspond with the authors for the solution. I hope that I will get the answers from them.